# Why does @ComponentScan behave differently for different configuration files?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm relatively new to Spring, and was following some examples.

During one of the examples I noticed that Spring wasn't mapping URI to methods.

I discovered that I put my @ComponentScan annotation on the wrong configuration class and fixed my problem.

So my question is why @ComponentScan works for one of these classes and not with the other?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.zerock.controller"}) // This Works.
public class ServletConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
//@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.zerock.controller"}) This Doesn't Work
public class RootConfig {
}
```

```
// How the two configuration classes are initialized
public class WebConfig extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{RootConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{ServletConfig.class};
    }
```

I've read that root config classes and servlet classes are set up differently in the application context hierarchy.

I suspect that has something to do with this, but I fail to see how that would cause this.

Comment: You are on the right path. It has to do with hierarchies. When controllers are in to root context they aren't detected by the Spring MVC infrastructure as it will only look into the context it itself is defined in (the child one, from the `ServletConfig.class`). This behavior can be changed through configuration as well, but it is the default.

Comment: @M. Deinum Oh so the controller bean itself is created, but Spring MVC doesn't bother to check the root context for controllers? I guess that makes sense since controllers should be servlet specific. Thank you for that comment.

Comment: try to move RootConfig to the same package as ServletConfig and it will probably work. In my opinion spring does not scan the package where RootConfig exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javadoc for [AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.html#createServletApplicationContext--) recommend to implement:

[getRootConfigClasses()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.html#getRootConfigClasses--) -- for "root" application context (non-web infrastructure) configuration.
[getServletConfigClasses()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.html#getServletConfigClasses--) -- for DispatcherServlet application context (Spring MVC infrastructure) configuration.

If an application context hierarchy is not required, applications may return all configuration via getRootConfigClasses()

So a @ComponentScan on the RootConfig should work if there are no duplication on the ServletConfig level.

Could you post the error you get and all classes?

I recommend you to place the RootConfig in the root of you packages and use @ComponentScan without specifying base package.

Comment: Putting both classes in to the root application context works like a charm. Apparently having an application context hierarchy is the root cause of this. Thanks.